# Fedora 38 - broke system while trying to install cuda toolkit

Tags: fedora, x11, nvidia, graphics, systemctl

I'd like to fix this rather than rerolling.

I performed a series of careless mistakes and broke my Fedora 38 install while trying to install CUDA toolkit using this guide: https://www.tecmint.com/install-nvidia-drivers-in-linux/ I figured it was one of these two lines (I undid the blacklist).

```
sudo dracut --force
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

Once I restarted, it set me into the text login.  When I tried starting X, nothing happened, so I tried to exit out and managed to.  I then tried some of these steps: https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-on-fedora-linux/ after doing "sudo dnf remove akmod-nvidia xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-cuda".  After reboots none of that worked.  So, I figured maybe I could reset to an initial setting.

I then found https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/upgrading-fedora-offline/ and did:

```
sudo dnf upgrade --refresh
sudo dnf install dnf-plugin-system-upgrade
sudo dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=38
```

Then I tried "sudo dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=39" since I'm already on 38.  One of the repos failed, so it suggested I add "--skip-broken" so I did that to the end, and that still failed (on mangohud).

I then found this https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/upgrading-fedora-offline/ which showed the inverse command I failed to find earlier, "systemctl set-default graphical.target".  Then, after rebooting, it hangs at a blank screen.  I can't use ctrl+alt+F{1-9} to switch to any of the other virtual consoles.  How do I proceed when I have no terminal interaction or login screen?

Answer (score 1):

The OP included the eventual solution as an edit to the question. I (terdon) am reproducing it here so the question can have an answer.

---

> **EDIT1**
>
> I saw that grub had the blacklist in it, so I removed all clauses with
> it and hit ctrl+x to boot.  I then edited `/etc/default/grub` to
> remove the corresponding section then `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-TQJYJ8g-U).  This got me to a bootable
> system.  Now, it's a matter of correcting the mess I caused after
> figuring out why the internet is barely working (whether or not I
> tether).
>
> **Edit 2** This machine's internet speed is 1-10mbps while my other machine is ~200mbps.  I think there's a setting I can change
> somewhere, perhaps in /etc/modprobe.d to fix this.  How do I fix this?
>
> **Edit 3** When I rebooted, I failed at getting into BIOS.  I remembered there was some weird issue that needed a reboot for my
> mobo's (MSI MAG B650) wireless card (Broadcom).  So, I figured it was
> a weird power state.  I turned off fast boot with `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup` and then the wireless speed was fixed.
>
> **Edit  4** I ended up using nvautoinstall from the copr repo by t0xic0der: `sudo nvautoinstall driver sudo nvautoinstall nvrepo sudo nvautoinstall plcuda`
>
> With this cuda toolkit was installed.  I tried to run blender and it
> crashed (powered off) multiple times while trying to render.  I think
> this has something to do with my multiseat setup, a PSU issue, power
> supply, or a driver problem.
>
> **Edit 5** I broke it again attempting to fix screen tearing trying to follow these directions:
> https://www.makeuseof.com/fix-screen-tearing-on-linux/
> `nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"` or the nvidia-settings directions
> added this to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.  I kept having issues logging in
> and then removed all nvidia clauses from grub (after hitting e to
> edit).  Once logged in, things were clearly buggy, programs would
> launch but not update but would store the after image of windows you
> dragged over them.  This made me realize I might need to go back to
> `systemctl set-default multi-user.target`.  So, I did that and then
> tried turning off fast boot with `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup`
> to hopefully get out of any weird power state like before.  After
> booting in without x, I did `sudo dnf update`, and `sudo dnf reinstall '*xorg*'`.  After this `startx` still gave the blank screen with the x
> logo for the cursor.  I switched to tty2 with `ctrl+alt+f2` and logged
> in again.  Ultimately, I had to remove the
> `ForceFullCompositionPipeline` line from `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.  I
> rebooted again, logged in, and typed `startx`.  I was in, and
> everything worked without any screen tearing.  Blender had some issues
> with cycles so I reinstalled the flatpak and it was fine.